# How to login / use the deployed service using JUJU

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, cloud

Deployed mongodb service using juju. It created a new virtual machine and deployed the mongodb service. How to access the newly created VM / Mongodb service. URL of the service is available from juju status command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running on local Linux environment then the machine will be in separate container using LCX, but still you can login those container machine.

=> First check the status
   **juju status**

environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.4.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: saucy
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.4.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.234
    instance-id: juju-local-machine-1
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64
services:
  mongodb:
    charm: cs:trusty/mongodb-1
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - mongodb
    units:
      mongodb/0:
        agent-state: started
        agent-version: 1.18.4.1
        machine: "1"

this is example of juju status command in my machine,

=> From this statement, the mongodb is running on the container machine '2'
  then enter the following command
   **juju ssh 2**

Now you can easily login to the container machine

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on on local Linux environment then the machine will be in separate container(with different subnet), so you will need to do the iptables forwarding for those machines. For AWS though things are different.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Anas.

Comment: Thanks @Onots, looking for some questions to answer and build my points.